# How to enable Python on a Chromebook for an account that is supervised with Family Link?

Tags: python, chromebook, parental-controls

I created a Google account for my son who is a minor.  It is managed by Google Family Link.

The problem is that it has a restriction for parental control by Google's Family Link which prevents this account from using Chromebook's "Linux (Beta)" mode.  As I understand correctly, Linux (Beta) mode is needed to be enabled to use the Linux terminal which allows the installation of Python so I can teach my son Python.

The question here is how can I enable the Chromebook so my son can learn Python and at the same time I can have parental control?

Comment: Please consider [edit]ing your question to clarify the exact steps you took and the initial (and subsequent) problems you encountered. Referring to other questions is fine, but not always helpful in resolving issues.

Comment: You don't need to install Linux to code with Python on a Chromebook.  There are numerous online coding sites which will do nicely,.  For example https://www.pythonanywhere.com/ or https://repl.it/.  Google for 'python online tutorial' for many learning sites which generally allow editing right on the site, for example https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-python-3

Comment: If you child needs to work offline, there are also Android apps for Python coding you could install though these will be more basic than the online option.  You would need to unblock these in the Family Link settings.